# Tips for profiling misbehaving Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, profiling, elisp, dot-emacs

I customize Emacs a lot. Recently, I added something to my .emacs configuration that sporadically pegs my CPU at 100%, but I really don't know what it is.

If I press C-g a bunch of times, eventually I'll get a message *below* the minibuffer asking me if I want to auto save my files and then if I want to abort emacs entirely. If I keep saying no and keeping pressing C-g, eventually I can get back to running emacs as normal. An hour or so later it will happen again.

I could keep going about like I am, commenting out various things I've added recently, restarting emacs, trying to narrow down the culprit, but it's slow going.

**Is there a way I can profile emacs directly to figure out what lisp function is hogging the CPU?**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The suggestion of setting `debug-on-quit` to `t` so that you can find out what Emacs is up to is a good one. You can think of this as being a form of sampling profiling with a single sample: often a single sample is all you need.

---

**Update:** Starting with version 24.3, Emacs contains *two* profilers. There's a (new) sampling profiler in `profiler.el`, and an (old) instrumenting profiler in `elp.el`.

The sampling profiler is [documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html). It's pretty straightforward to use:

> To begin profiling, type `M-x profiler-start`. You can choose to profile by processor usage, memory usage, or both. After doing some work, type `M-x profiler-report` to display a summary buffer for each resource that you chose to profile. When you have finished profiling, type `M-x profiler-stop`.

Here's some example output from a `cpu+mem` profiler session with the [Perforce/Emacs integration](https://github.com/gareth-rees/p4.el) that I maintain. I've expanded the topmost function (`progn`) in order to find out [where the CPU time and memory use is coming from](https://github.com/gareth-rees/p4.el/issues/112).

```
Function                                            Bytes    %
- progn                                        26,715,850  29%
  - let                                        26,715,850  29%
    - while                                    26,715,850  29%
      - let                                    26,715,850  29%
        - cond                                 26,715,850  29%
          - insert                             26,715,850  29%
            + c-after-change                   26,713,770  29%
            + p4-file-revision-annotate-links       2,080   0%
+ let                                          20,431,797  22%
+ call-interactively                           12,767,261  14%
+ save-current-buffer                          10,005,836  11%
+ while                                         8,337,166   9%
+ p4-annotate-internal                          5,964,974   6%
+ p4-annotate                                   2,821,034   3%
+ let*                                          2,089,810   2%
```

You can see that the culprit is `c-after-change`, so it looks as though I could save a lot of CPU time and memory by [locally binding `inhibit-modification-hooks` to `t` around this code](https://github.com/gareth-rees/p4.el/commit/4e015793877a56c4ccb1bfbb6e2d278be7c078d8).

---

You can also use the Emacs Lisp Profiler. This is rather under-documented: you'll have to read the comments in `elp.el` for the details, but basically you run `elp-instrument-package` to turn on profiling for all the functions with a given prefix, and then `elp-results` to see the results.

Here's some typical output after typing `M-x elp-instrument-package RET c- RET`, fontifying 4,000 lines of C, and then running `elp-results` (and using `elp-sort-by-function` to sort by call count):

```
Function Name                  Call Count  Elapsed Time  Average Time
=============================  ==========  ============  ============
c-skip-comments-and-strings    107         0.0           0.0
c-valid-offset                 78          0.0           0.0
c-set-offset                   68          0.031         0.0004558823
c-end-of-macro                 52          0.0           0.0
c-neutralize-CPP-line          52          0.0           0.0
c-font-lock-invalid-string     20          0.0           0.0
c-set-style-1                  19          0.031         0.0016315789
...
```

In your particular case the profiler doesn't help immediately, because you don't know which package is at fault. But if you can make a guess (or use `debug-on-quit` to find it for sure) then the profiler can help you diagnose the problem in detail.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried: `Options->Enter debugger on Quit/C-g`? (this is on emacs22)

If you need to debug start-up of emacs: use `emacs -q --no-site-file`, visit your `.emacs` (or `site-start.el` or whatever), activate the menu item `Options->Enter debugger on Quit/C-g`, and then menu item `Emacs-Lisp->Evaluate buffer` and `C-g` when it appears to freeze. There may be a easier way of doing this.........

Answer (score 6):

With dope.el you can profile entire .emacs or multiple elisp files loaded at startup. Download it from [www.gnufans.net/~deego/pub/emacspub/lisp-mine/dope/](http://www.gnufans.net/~deego/pub/emacspub/lisp-mine/dope/)

`M-x dope-quick-start` will show a little introduction tutorial.

**Edit:** The original URL is now defunct, but there is a working mirror on Git Hub:
https://raw.github.com/emacsmirror/dope/master/dope.el

Comment: Thank you for the dope package. I was able to reconfigure my .emacs to load in less than a second using this package. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not, strictly speaking, an answer to your question, but rather than doing the comment-out-and-restart thing, you can start emacs with the `-q` option, load your .emacs into a buffer and evaluate each sexpr yourself with C-x C-e to track down the offending one.

Comment: Good point, I do eval-expression all the time, but this mode of debugging hadn't initially occurred to me.

Comment: You don't want to evaluate each sexp in turn (unless you have very few).  Use a binary search, with `eval-region'.